# Select values next to matching cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I have a spreadsheet with two columns, `key` and `name`. Right now, the name gets repeated multiple times per value. I set up a formula to get unique values in name, but now I need to get a list of all the values of the cells that match that column.

So if I have the name 'Brian', and there are 4 of them with index values of 5, 6, 7, and 8, I need a formula to take/use the value of `C1` to look at `B:B` and give me all values in `A:A`.

Is this possible?

[image: example of data]
[image: Desired result]

Comment: Please post an image of your data or a sample.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Added.

Comment: Could you please add a sample of how the result would look like?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz My apologies, that should have been in the first image.

Comment: Are you trying to get index values from `Column A` for values like `Brian`.

Comment: @Harun24HR Yes. There was an image in there that showed what I wanted it to look like but an edit removed it.

Comment: There is an easy [tag:textjoin] solution to this. If your version of excel doesn't have [tag:textjoin] then look at the [tag:textjoin] forum for pre-Office365 alternatives.

Comment: @CodyHarness Please add again.

Comment: @Harun24HR Added

Comment: So, you want only excel or `VBA` macro is okay?

Comment: Well technically I'm using Google Sheets, so excel would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets)'s D1 put this formula in and drag down.

```
=arrayformula(textjoin(" ", true, if(B:B=C1, A:A, "")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## CONCIF (UDF)

### In Excel

```
=CONCIF($B$1:$B$20,$C1,$A$1:$A$20)
```

### In VBA

```vb
Option Explicit

Function CONCIF(MatchRange As Range, ByVal MatchValue As Variant, _
        ConcatRange As Range, _
        Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = " ") As String

    Dim vntM As Variant   ' Match Array
    Dim vntC As Variant   ' Concat Array
    Dim Nor As Long       ' Number of Rows
    Dim i As Long         ' Row Counter
    Dim strC As String    ' Concat String
    Dim strR As String    ' Result String

    ' Check number of rows in MatchRange is less than or equal to number
    ' of rows in Concat Range.
    If MatchRange.Rows.Count <= ConcatRange.Rows.Count Then
        ' Write number of rows in MatchRange to Number of Rows.
        Nor = MatchRange.Rows.Count
      Else
        ' Write number of rows in ConcatRange to Number of Rows.
        Nor = ConcatRange.Rows.Count
    End If

    ' Check if Number of Rows is equal to 1, which would mean there
    ' can only be one match.
    If Nor = 1 Then
        ' Check if the value in 1-cell MatchRange is equal to MatchValue.
        If MatchRange.Cells(1, 1) = MatchValue Then
            ' Write value of 1-cell ConcatRange, converted to string, to CONCIF.
            CONCIF = CStr(ConcatRange.Cells(1, 1))
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Copy the range defined by 1st Nor number of cells in 1st column of
    ' MatchRange to 2D 1-based 1-column Match Array.
    vntM = MatchRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(Nor)
    ' Copy the range defined by 1st Nor number of cells in 1st column of
    ' ConcatRange to 2D 1-based 1-column Concat Array.
    vntC = ConcatRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(Nor)

    ' Loop through elements (rows) of Match/Concat Arrays.
    For i = 1 To Nor
        ' Check if current value in MatchArray is equal to MatchValue.
        If vntM(i, 1) = MatchValue Then
            ' Write current value in ConcatArray to Concat String.
            strC = CStr(vntC(i, 1))
            ' Check if Concat String is NOT "".
            If strC <> "" Then
                ' Check if Result String is NOT "".
                If strR <> "" Then
                    ' Concatenate current value of Result String, Delimiter
                    ' and Concat String, to Result String.
                    strR = strR & Delimiter & strC
                  Else
                    ' Write Concat String to Result String (only once).
                    strR = strC
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' Write Result String to CONCIF.
    CONCIF = strR

End Function
```

---

[image]